# What is the easiest way to ignore a poison error on Mutex?

Tags: rust

I've come up with this macro:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

macro_rules! lock_ignore_poison {
    ($l:expr) => { 
        {
            let lock = $l.lock();
            match lock {
                Err(e) => e.into_inner(),
                Ok(guard) => guard
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
    println!("{}", lock_ignore_poison!(x));
}
```

but I'd like to know if this is the easiest way to ignore the poison and always return the object.

Comment: If the types that you're sharing have atomic counterparts, e.g. `AtomicU32`, you could use those instead of mutex guarded values. Then you won't have to deal with poisoning. Since operations are atomic, whether a sharing thread panics or not isn't a problem.

Comment: Maybe you can use an alternate Mutex without posioning, such as [`parking_lot::Mutex`](https://amanieu.github.io/parking_lot/parking_lot/struct.Mutex.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an `ignore_poison` extension method I've used in my own projects:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, LockResult, Mutex};

/// Extension methods for [`LockResult`].
///
/// [`LockResult`]: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/type.LockResult.html
pub trait LockResultExt {
    type Guard;

    /// Returns the lock guard even if the mutex is [poisoned].
    ///
    /// [poisoned]: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#poisoning
    fn ignore_poison(self) -> Self::Guard;
}

impl<Guard> LockResultExt for LockResult<Guard> {
    type Guard = Guard;

    fn ignore_poison(self) -> Guard {
        self.unwrap_or_else(|e| e.into_inner())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
    println!("{}", x.lock().ignore_poison());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nightly Rust and are okay with using experimental features, you could use [`Result::into_ok_or_err()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.into_ok_or_err) to make this a bit mor concise:

```rust
#![feature(result_into_ok_or_err)]

fn force_into_inner<T>(lock: std::sync::Mutex<T>) -> T {
    lock.into_inner().map_err(std::sync::PoisonError::into_inner).into_ok_or_err()
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=14123f719aed9215ba27a62a62863735)